# bash | регулярка

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, штрихкод

Пишу в баше регулярку. Есть место, где в строке может присутствовать маленькая латинская буква или `m_`. `[a-z|m_]` не подходит. А как тогда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон `[a-z|m_]` является "скобочным выражением" (*bracket expression*), который находит буквы из диапазона a-z, символ `|`, `m` или `_`. По сути, этот шаблон равен `[_a-z|]`. `m_` не является здесь *последовательностью символов*.

Вы можете использовать `[a-z]|m_`, например

```bsh
rx='[a-z]|m_'
if [[ $string =~ $rx ]]; then
  echo "Найдено совпадение в ${string}";
else
  echo "Совпадения не найдено в ${string}";
fi
```

Другой вариант: `[[:lower:]]|m_`.

Регулярные выражения в Bash должны следовать стандарту POSIX ERE, и приведённый выше шаблон означает следующее:

- `[[:lower:]]` - буква в нижнем регистре
- `|` - оператор ИЛИ
- `m_` - строка `m_`.

В вашем более длинном регулярном выражении в `grep` нужно поместить `[a-z]|m_` в группу (подмаску) `([a-z]|m_)`, иначе оператор ИЛИ "поделит" всё выражение на две альтернативные части:

```bsh
grep -E '^[A-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*\s+(a-z|m_)[0-9a-zA-Z]*;$' file
```

Comment: а почему _ привязывается к |? оно не среагирует на a_?

Comment: @AndreyKomisarov Я добавил описание, надеюсь, теперь понятнее.

Comment: У меня такое:
grep -oP "^[A-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*\s+[a-z|m_][0-9a-zA-Z]*_?;$" < "$1"
Не пропускает такую строку:
T m__;

Comment: @AndreyKomisarov Тогда зачем вы пишите Bash, когда у вас проблема с grep? Обновите  вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: какая? (там два _ в один слиплись)